# Android Accessibility Service: Dispatch Multitouch Gesture possible?

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility, touch

I am currently extending an existing app with touch gestures like swipe.
Basically everything works fine **if** I am simulating just **1** "finger". But as soon as I am adding multiple Strokes to the GestureBuilder and dispatch them it doesn't work.
So my main question is: *Is it possible to dispatch multitouch gestures or is it currently just possible to dispatch single touch gestures?*

I've tried to add multiple Strokes to the GestureBuilder, dispatch them and watched them on the emulator with Androids defaults "show touches" implementation.
The Strokes are all looking fine in terms of direction, start point, end points etc. They are also simulated and performed simultanously BUT it seems that the device doesn't recognize them as multitouch.